# How to address the new "Task-Completed" QgsMessageBar in Python?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am really amazed what huge steps the QGIS development has taken in the last months. The new iconset, the improved [Print composer](http://anitagraser.com/2013/03/17/print-composer-2-0-take-1-guide-lines/) and many more changes to be seen in QGIS 2.0 are really awesome!

Among many other cool improvements there is also this nifty blue task-bar, which I find very appealing. 
[image: Text says: Save completed: Export to vector file finished]

Is it possible to address this bar in python for scripts and plugins (for instance to show a small message after finished computations)?
I am asking this question here, because i believe that many QGIS developers also visit this Q&A site.

PS: The bar is only visible in QGIS dev and only for some operations.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It sure is:

```
iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Header","MessageBody", QgsMessageBar.WARNING, 2)
```

the last arg is a timeout in seconds, if it's not supplied then it will stay until the user closes it.

You can even add you own control to the messagebar:

```
widget = iface.messageBar().createMessage("Test","Testing")
combo = QComboBox()
widget.layout().addWidget(combo)
iface.messageBar().pushWidget(widget, QgsMessageBar.WARNING)
combo.addItems("ASD")
```

[image]

http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsMessageBar.html#a0b305c7215d75243b4237c299f0f7723

Comment: @Nathan i'm using QProgressBar instead of QComboBox. i'm unable to align the progressbar label in the right side, currently its showing in middle of the progressbar with % symbol.

Comment: @venkat that is the style of the progress bar.  Have a look at Qt stylesheets on how to change that, or there might be a label property.

Comment: @Nathan i already raised the question regarding this but i didnt get any answer so far. kindly check this link.there i explained with screenshot and source code.                          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434215/how-to-align-qprogressbar-label-in-qgis-messagebar

Comment: @venkat answered over there for you