# Is it possible to show our custom message in QGIS Status bar using python?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Is there any way to show our custom message in Qgis Status bar using python? Just like in arcgis `IApplication.statusbar.message(0) = "Please wait..."`

like that is there any option to show progressbar in Qgis like `IApplication.progressbar.show()`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## StatusBar

There is **iface.mainWindow().statusBar()** which returns a [QStatusBar](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstatusbar.html)

```py
iface.mainWindow().statusBar().showMessage( u"Hello World" )
```

[image]

## MessageBar

Starting from QGIS 2.0 there is also [QgsMessageBar](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsMessageBar.html) which is able to display unobtrusive messages

```py
iface.messageBar().pushInfo(u'My Plugin says', u'Hey there')
```

[image]

### Advanced

The message bar can also show any QWidget (like a [QProgressBar](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprogressbar.html)) with a close button and a timeout (5 seconds in the example).

```py
from PyQt4.QtGui import QProgressBar
from qgis.gui import QgsMessageBar
msgBar = iface.messageBar()

pb = QProgressBar( msgBar )
msgBar.pushWidget( pb, QgsMessageBar.INFO, 5 )

msg = msgBar.createMessage( u'Hello World' )
msgBar.pushWidget( msg, QgsMessageBar.WARNING, 5 )
```

[image]

More info about QgsMessageBar can be found in this answer by NathanW [How to address the new "Task-Completed" QgsMessageBar in Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57067/how-to-adress-the-new-task-completed-bar-in-python?rq=1)
Thanks for pointing out Curlew

### Legacy

In the python console for QGIS < 1.9 it would be:

```py
qgis.utils.iface.mainWindow().statusBar().showMessage( u"Hello World" )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Matthias..is there any option for progressbar?

Comment: In the QgsMessageBar you're able to display any kind of widget. I would not know that this is possible in the status bar.

Comment: I am very new to qgis and python.. could you please give me example for QgsMessageBar? and what is the meaning of using 'u' prefix in "Hello world"

Comment: The u prefix is for unicode strings. It will also work without this.

For the QgsMessageBar you have to get the current development version of QGIS or wait for the release of 2.0.

Comment: Also see Nathans answer on how to push a widget to the new messagebar http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57067/how-to-adress-the-new-task-completed-bar-in-python?rq=1