# (X,Y,Z) Coordinate tracking in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, data

I am working on a Python script which will give me the x,y and depth coordinates in QGIS. I have depth as an attribute of the raster layer. My objective is to get a status bar which shows x,y and the depth coordinate when the mouse is at a certain point of the canvas. The code I have used is:

```
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import QAction, QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import SIGNAL, Qt


class MyWnd(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self,layer):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.statusBar().showMessage(u"x:-,y:-")
    self.canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
    self.canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.white)

    self.canvas.setExtent(layer.extent())
    self.canvas.setLayerSet([QgsMapCanvasLayer(layer)])

    self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)

    actionZoomIn = QAction("Zoom in", self)
    actionZoomOut = QAction("Zoom out", self)
    actionPan = QAction("Pan", self)

    actionZoomIn.setCheckable(True)
    actionZoomOut.setCheckable(True)
    actionPan.setCheckable(True)

    self.connect(actionZoomIn, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.zoomIn)
    self.connect(actionZoomOut, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.zoomOut)
    self.connect(actionPan, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.pan)

    self.toolbar = self.addToolBar("Canvas actions")
    self.toolbar.addAction(actionZoomIn)
    self.toolbar.addAction(actionZoomOut)
    self.toolbar.addAction(actionPan)

    # create the map tools
    self.toolPan = QgsMapToolPan(self.canvas)
    self.toolPan.setAction(actionPan)
    self.toolZoomIn = QgsMapToolZoom(self.canvas, False) # false = in
    self.toolZoomIn.setAction(actionZoomIn)
    self.toolZoomOut = QgsMapToolZoom(self.canvas, True) # true = out
    self.toolZoomOut.setAction(actionZoomOut)

    self.pan()

  def zoomIn(self):
    self.canvas.setMapTool(self.toolZoomIn)

  def zoomOut(self):
    self.canvas.setMapTool(self.toolZoomOut)

  def pan(self):
    self.canvas.setMapTool(self.toolPan)

  def eventFilter(self,source,event):
    if event.type()==Qt.Event.MouseMove:
      if event.buttons()==Qt.NoButton:
        pos=event.pos()
        x=pos.x()
        y=pos.y()
        p=selfcanvas.getCoordinateTransform().toMapCoordinates(x,y)
        self.statusBar().showMessage(u"x:%s,y:%s" %(p.x(),p.y()))
      else:
        pass
    return QMainWindow.eventFilter(self,source,event)
```

This file I have saved as mywnd.py in the Python27 folder
Then in Python console in QGIS I use:

```
import mywnd


w=mywnd.MyWnd(qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer())
w.show()
```

This gives me my active layer but I still can't figure out how to get the values of x and y in the statusbar. I also am not very good at Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to show our custom message in QGIS Status bar using python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58750/is-it-possible-to-show-our-custom-message-in-qgis-status-bar-using-python)

Comment: Well, no, I am getting the layer which I am working on in a separate window and I need the coordinates. This link would have been useful if I wanted to give a custom message. The thing is I am not able to connect the eventFilter and MyWnd Classes.

Comment: Did you try to use [`self.installEventFilter(self)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter) in `__init__`?

Comment: I had not tried that before, it now Gives me an error saying 'Qt' has no attribute 'Event' at the line `event.type()==Qt.Event.Mouse.Move:`

Comment: Then 1) that's a hint that the event is called (which is good) and 2) that's a hint that the event code has a bug (which is bad). -> replace `Qt.Event.Mouse.Move` with `QEvent.MouseMove` ;)

Comment: Okay, no errors in code now, but It still does not show me x and y coordinates it just shows me x:-,y:- as defined in the line `self.statusBar().showMessage(u"x:-,y:-")`, I have put `self.installEventFilter(self)` after `self.pan()` and before `def zoomIn(self):`

Comment: Hmmm... I think you need to enable [`mouseTracking`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59729/discussion-between-matthias-kuhn-and-sunny-naik).

Answer (score 5):

Some notes

## An event filter...

... [needs to be installed](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter) or it's never going to be called

```
def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.installEventFilter(self)
```

## The event types...

... are enumerated in [QEvent::Type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#Type-enum), so you need to use `QEvent.MouseMove`.

## Mouse tracking ...

... is disabled by default (for performance reason), so you need to explicitly enable it if you want to receive move events it in the event filter even when no button is clicked

```
self.setMouseTracking(True)
```

## Code style

### New style connections are better

Use something like

```
self.actionZoomIn.triggered.connect(self.zoomIn)
```

### Wildcard imports

... are discouraged.

You are already doing things correctly for `from PyQt4.QtGui import xxx`. Do the same for the `qgis` imports. Do not use `from qgis.gui import *` but instead

```
from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvas, QgsMapToolPan, etc.
```