# Showing dialog box even though QGIS is freezing

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, popup, pyqt5

I have a long script in PyQGIS that contains three processing tasks after another.
I want to display a pop up box (like "QProgressDialog"-Box) for each task when it is finished.

Example:
When Task 1 (Merge) has finished, I want a box to pop up ("Task 1 (Merge) is finished). Then the Task 2 is executing and when it is finished i want another box to pop up...

Unfortunately only the first "QProgressDialog"-Box is shown and QGIS freezes as it is processing.

How can I achieve to display a pop up box (or even better a progress bar) when QGIS is freezing?

[image]

My code is:

```
bar = QProgressDialog("Operation in progress", "Cancel",0,100)
bar.show()
bar.setRange(0,0)

#the processing tasks are following below
...
```

Comment: QGIS freezes as it is processing because you need to set 'setWindowModality' for **QProgressDialog** object and a sleep (delay) time for each task. Another issue is referred to 'setRange' method. It was already set in **QProgressDialog** object (as parameters ..., 0, 100).  Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

QGIS freezes as it is processing because you need to set 'setWindowModality' for **QProgressDialog** object and a sleep (delay) time for each task. Another issue is referred to 'setRange' method. It was already set in **QProgressDialog** object (as parameters ..., 0, 100). So, for three processing tasks following code works as expected:

```
import time

m = ""

bar = QProgressDialog(m, "Cancel", 0, 100)

bar.setWindowModality(Qt.WindowModal)

m = "Operation 1 in progress"
bar.setLabelText(m)

for i in range(101):
    time.sleep(0.05)
    bar.setValue(i)

m = "Operation 2 in progress"
bar.setLabelText(m)

for i in range(101):
    time.sleep(0.05)
    bar.setValue(i)

m = "Operation 3 in progress"
bar.setLabelText(m)

for i in range(101):
    time.sleep(0.05)
    bar.setValue(i)
```

Following image is showing your "freezing behavior" when 'setWindowModality' line in above code is commented.

[image]

When 'setWindowModality' line is not commented, code behavior is as expected:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be achieved with dialog boxes. However, there is something better: the **MessageBar**. Have a look at: [Is it possible to show our custom message in QGIS Status bar using python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58750/is-it-possible-to-show-our-custom-message-in-qgis-status-bar-using-python/58754)

Comment: Thank you! I implemented the status bar in my plugin code but the message displays not before the whole process is finished.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to refer to the MessageBar and the progress bar example in the above linked answer